# Invoking com instance methods using Reflection in .NET

Tags: c#, reflection, com, system.reflection

I'm trying to use `Type.InvokeMember` to dynamically call a method in a com object during runtime.

The method I'm trying to execute is `DTE2.ExecuteCommand` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte._dte.executecommand.aspx).

Here is the current code I'm using and doesn't seem to work at all.

```
var DTE2 dte = ....;
var T = typeof(DTE2);
T.InvokeMember("ExecuteCommand",
                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, 
                null,
                dte, 
                new object[] { "File.New", "" });
```

I get the following error

```
Method 'EnvDTE80.DTE2.ExecuteCommand' not found.
```

On further inspections I did see `ExecuteCommand` method info when using the following code.

```
var methods = T.GetMethods();
```

So I believe I need to change my `BindingFlags.InvokeMethod` to something else. What would that be?

Comment: Have you tried combining `BindingFlags.NonPublic`? That method appears private.

Comment: `DTE2` is an interface

Comment: You forgot BindingFlags.Instance.  Hard to see the point to this code, you already reference the interface type so you might as well use it.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead `BindingFlags.NonPublic` doesn't seem to work. 
@DuncanSmartso we can't call `InvokeMethod` on interfaces?
@HansPassant `BindingFlags.Instance` doesn't seem to work. I actually need to access it from nlua so will not have a reference. But I wanted to code it in c# first as I wasn't being able to run it in c#.

Comment: You should be combining these flags.. not using one of them..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead combined all ` BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance` doesn't seem to work. Also tried combinations like `BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic` didnt work. Any ideas how to get the binding flags from a `MethodInfo`?

Comment: seems like I made a silly mistake. I was using `"File.New"` instead of `"File.NewFile"` and that was throwing exception.